Custom Post Type taxonomical permalink URLs work - but display incorrectly as "%variable%" name rather than value in the editor
Following the instructions from this thread, I have custom post type taxonomical permalink URLs working.
However, when the permalink is actually displayed in the admin or editor, it reverts to using the variable name (e.g. /%taxonomy_name%/) rather than the variable values (e.g. /podcast/).
E.g. My taxonomy is called podcast. My custom post type is called podcast_episode.
I can create a top-level podcast "foo" and I create a podcast_episode post titled "123". url.test/podcast/foo/123 works.
I can create a 2nd-level podcast underneath "foo" called "bar", then I create a podcast_episode titled "1234" url.test/podcast/foo/bar/1234 works.
However, in the actual classic editor, the displayed permalink is url.test/podcast/%taxonomy_name%/123and url.test/podcast/%taxonomy_name%/1234.
In the table view for all podcast_episodes, pressing "View" on a row also points to the same broken URL with %taxonomy_name% in it.
How can I update it so that the displayed permalink in the WordPress admin section matches the actual URL?
This is my current code:
// functions.php
function _s_create_custom_post_types() {
    register_post_type(
        'podcast_episode',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Podcast Episodes'),
                'singular_name' => __('Podcast Episode'),
                'add_new' => __('Add New'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Podcast Episode'),
                'view_item' => __('View Item'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
                'search_items' => __('Search Items'),
                'not_found' => __('Not Found'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Not Found in Trash')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            // 'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'podcast/%taxonomy_name%',
            ),
            'taxonomies' => array('podcast_episode'),
            'query_var' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail',),
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', '_s_create_custom_post_types');

function _s_add_custom_taxonomies() {
    // Add new "podcast" taxonomy to "podcast_episode" post type
    register_taxonomy('podcast', 'podcast_episode', array(
        // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x('Podcasts', 'taxonomy general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Podcast', 'taxonomy singular name'),
            'search_items' =>  __('Search Podcasts'),
            'all_items' => __('All Podcasts'),
            'parent_item' => __('Parent Podcast'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Location:'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Podcast'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Podcast'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Podcast or Podcast Season'),
            'menu_name' => __('Podcasts'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'podcast',
            'with_front' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
        'query_var' => true,
    ));
}
add_action('init', '_s_add_custom_taxonomies');

// Fix URLs
function vk_query_vars($qvars) {
    if (is_admin()) return $qvars;
    $custom_taxonomy = 'podcast';
    if (array_key_exists($custom_taxonomy, $qvars)) {
        $custom_post_type = 'podcast_episode';


        $pathParts = explode('/', $qvars[$custom_taxonomy]);
        $numParts = sizeof($pathParts);

        $lastPart = array_pop($pathParts);
        $post = get_page_by_path($lastPart, OBJECT, $custom_post_type);
        if ($post && !is_wp_error($post)) {
            $qvars['p'] = $post->ID;
            $qvars['post_type'] = $custom_post_type;
        }
    }
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter('request', 'vk_query_vars');

function filter_post_type_link($link, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type != 'podcast')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'podcast_episode')) {
        $link = str_replace('%taxonomy_name%', get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($cats)->term_id, 'podcast', false, '/', true), $link); // see custom function defined below
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {
    $chain = '';
    $parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

    if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
        return $parent;
    }

    if ($nicename)
        $name = $parent->slug;
    else
        $name = $parent->name;

    if ($parent->parent && ($parent->parent != $parent->term_id) && !in_array($parent->parent, $visited)) {
        $visited[] = $parent->parent;
        $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent->parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);
    }

    if ($link) {
        // nothing, can't get this working :(
    } else
        $chain .= $name . $separator;
    return $chain;
}



Anytime you modify the 'rewrite' arguments for a CPT or taxonomy, remember to flush your rewrite rules:
Easiest way is to visit Settings → Permalinks in WP Admin and click “Save.”
